# Pepper flash plugin is installed but it doesn't appear in the plugin section in chromium on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: chromium, plugins

I installed Pepper flash plugin using the software centre and installed fresh flash player but the plugins don't appear in the plug in section.How to get it on chromium?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install pepper teacup
 sudo apt-get install flash-plugin-installer
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall chromium firefox
```

and it might work fine this way.